# passing python3 file stream to C++ extern function

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-extensions

Okay there, i have some code in python that opens a file -> process it -> and writes data to other file.

```
def ELECrypt(myFile, outFile, code):
    Code = list(bytes(code,'utf-8'))
    with open(myFile, 'rb') as bFil:
        with open(outFile, 'wb') as bOutFil:
            while True :
                data = bytearray(bFil.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
                if not data: break
                processIt(data, Code)
                bOutFil.write(data)
```

It works fine, but it is too slow.
So, i wrote a C++ program that does similar thing and I want to know if it is possible to make it callable from python

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int CHUNK_SIZE = 1*1024*1024;
void ELECrypt(ifstream& myFile, ofstream& outFile, unsigned char Code[], int CodeLen){
    unsigned char* fChunk = new unsigned char[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int readCount;
    while (myFile.read((char *)fChunk, CHUNK_SIZE) || myFile.gcount() > 0)
    {
        ...Processing a data block
        outFile.write((char *)fChunk, myFile.gcount());
    }
    delete [] fChunk;
}
```

Yeah-yeah, I know there might be a lot of work, but i can`t even find where to read about arguments that can be passed by python to c++ extension

Comment: Have you checked that it is actually performing measurably better?

Comment: You can try swig. http://swig.org/

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, on an image if 6.4mb C++ works like less then second, and python like more then 10 seconds